# Is it safe to pass "$?" to a subroutine?

Tags: perl, error-handling, system

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;


my $ret = system( 'my_command' );

error_message( $? ) if $ret;

sub error_message {
    my $error = shift;
    if ( $error == -1 ) {
        print "failed to execute: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ( $error & 127 ) {
        printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n", 
        ( $error & 127 ), ( $error & 128 ) ? 'with' : 'without';
    }
    else {
        printf "child exited with value %d\n", $error >> 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: @darch: Because `$@` is notoriously finicky, and there is no immediate reason why `$?` shouldn't be the same.

Comment: The problem is more the use of $!, read perlvar $!

Comment: @MkV: Well `$!` at least tends to change synchronously. The problem with `$@` is that is can be overwritten or localised by an error handler or a signal handler. Either way the point is that there is no immediate reason why `$?` is safe to pass around.

Comment: @Borodin `$@` is as safe to pass around as any other value.  It's not safe to keep using the *name*, because the value behind that name may be changed by action at a distance.  But its value is another matter.  This code has problems with `$!`, but that's because it uses the name at a point when its value may have become irrelevant.  Passing around values does not get more or less safe as a function of how you got access to those values.

Comment: @darch: I think you're being unnecessarily picky. It's understood that a variable's name and its value are used interchangeably, regardless of the fact that it's *impossible* to pass `$?` as a parameter to a subroutine if you're being that strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also interested in $!, you should be passing it too, dealing with it immediately after the system call, not relying on it to be correct deep in your sub.  As long as you don't have code before shifting the arguments off @*, you should be fine.  If you do anything that might change $! or $? before shifting them off @* or setting them to the values in @_ then you will be looking at the changed values, not the values after your initial error.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$?` represents an error from another application that the Perl code has started through bacticks, `system` or a pipe open, or perhaps through a  call to `wait`.

As long as you aren't working with multiple child processes then in general you are safe, but to be sure you can capture the value immediately after the call that sets `$?`, like this

```
my $ret = system( 'my_command' );
my $child_error = $?;

error_message($child_error) if $ret;
```